# How to list directories and subdirectories with a directory as argument (Bash)

Tags: ubuntu, bash

The task is to make a bash script in ubuntu. It's supposed to take a directory as an argument, and list all directories and subdirectories from that argument. I don't have much experience with bash, can you help me out?

Comment: `shopt -s globstar nullglob; ls -l **/*; shopt -u globstar nullglob`?

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways/utils you could do this. If you can't afford to install `tree` you might try and use the ones available out of the box.

### List directories using find

`find . -type d`

It depends on what exactly are you planning to do with the results. I suggest you [look at this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17009555/289594) for other options and inspiration.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `tree` [[1](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tree)] command.

```
  tree -d "$1"
```

The `-d` option will list only the directories.

The `$1` is the 1st parameter you pass to the script.

By the way do not parse the output of command as tree or `ls` to avoid problem related withe space tab and newline that are characters allowed inside a name of a file or of a directory.

In the latter case you can use `find`.
Ask `man find` in a shell or search e.g. on this site about it.